# C# object reference in static void main

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I'm trying to subscribe to an event in static void main, but i get the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field,method etc"

Here is part of the code :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...

        Factorial Fact = new Factorial();
        Fact.Progression += new Factorial.ProgressEventHandler(Progress);
        ...

    }
```

How do I get rid of the error? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it inline.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...

    Factorial Fact = new Factorial();
    Fact.Progression += (s,e) => { /*Do stuff*/ };
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to see for sure without the full code, but I'm guessing your `Progress` function is not static. If you change it to be static, that code should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have references to non static members of a class inside a static function.

Your code has variables defined outside the Main method. Mark those as static and everything should be ok.